# How can I trigger the Strip Club mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just completed the mission when Trevor took over the strip club. Instead of continuing the story I went off with Michael and did some side missions. Now when I try to go to the strip club to trigger the mission it wouldn't take.

I've tried playing other characters and just playing until something happened but nothing has happened... I've tried calling certain people and bringing all three characters to the strip club but nothing is working. It's gotten to the point when I'm just so frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are the right character firstly. You have to go through the curtains where you get a private dance from the strippers, go right and Trevor should be there against a fridge